# assigning a string's chars to an int array assigns the wrong value

Tags: c#, arrays, string

if I assing a string with

```
string = "12";
```

and check its value with

```
Console.Write(string[0] + string[1]);
```

it returns 12 as intended.

but if I assign string[0] to an int array via

```
int[0] = string[0];
```

and check its value via

```
Console.Write(int[0]);
```

it returns 49.

even if I used `Convert.ToInt32()` while assigning, it still returned 49.

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MnzH.png)

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3h5h.png)

Can you help me out here?

Comment: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Note that (after fixing your pseudo-code so that it's valid) the first snippet prints 99 as well. Please provide a [mcve] (not pseudo-code that uses keywords as variable names) that prints "12" with your first piece of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning 49 because you are trying to convert the value `1` to integer and the ASCII value of `1` is 49. if you want to print the value as `1` to need to use string only, then you can use the code similar to this `int.Parse(stringValue);` or you can use `TryParse` method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting the char '1' into an int which works. Which according to the ASCII table is 49.

For example assigning 'A' to int[0] would set its value to 65.

Answer (score 0):

You must just use int.Parse().